# After vue3 uses the vuex page to refresh, the store is lost

Tags: vuex

When I use vue3, I use store. When the page is loaded, I want to get the previously stored store, but after refreshing the page, it is undefined

Answer (score 0):

this is my answer

```js
 setup() {
    const store = useStore();
 
        // 在页面加载时读取sessionStorage里的状态信息
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('store')) {
      // 存储状态
      store.replaceState(Object.assign({}, store.state, JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('store'))))
    }
    // 在页面刷新时将vuex里的信息保存到sessionStorage里
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
      sessionStorage.setItem('store', JSON.stringify(store.state))
    })
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
```